# Prevent public from accessing my root directory and seeing the files etc

Tags: database, .htaccess, server, directory

I'm programming an app and wanted to link it like an iframe (WebView in Android for those who know) but when I make a folder in my webserver it is possible to be accessed by anyone in the world by just browsing with their browser in the directories and I do NOT want anyone be able to look up for example profile pictures or other sensible stuff of my future clients/user.

How do I protect my app on the web from being accessed like that? I heard of `.htaccess` but is that little file really hack proofed? Can my data on the server be spilled other how? How is the industry, like for example "Tinder", doing to protect their clients data in the form of pictures?

I planned to have a folder called "User" in my root of the server and from there I planned on making folders like "User1" and filling those with my users stuff for the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's good way to do that. You just need to add line bellow to prevent access to directory indexes

```
Options -Indexes
```

Sometimes frameworks and cms systems making empty index.html file and putting it in every directory they prevent access, that is better from security view because in case of wrong setup of your server files can be shown, but .htaccess solution is much simpler. Also you must be sure that people can't access .htaccess file directly, that is already part of default webserver setup but if you can access .htaccess file through url you need to add this to server configuration:

```
<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

I suppose your server is apache, but even if it's not every other server have some alternative to .htaccess, and example pointed with index.html file will always work.